# Using IIS 7.0: urlCompression with heavy ViewState enterprise application

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis-7, compression

[IIS 7.0: urlCompression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347437.aspx)

What is the best configuration of this feature in an enterprise application with heavy ViewState usage, large content pages along with highly configurable data?

Assume:

- Strong database server
- Web farm
- Load balanced

What I am not asking is alternatives to boost performance, just this feature specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the CPU on your webserver can handle it, I would turn on "doDynamicCompression".  We've seen that the page size is 30% smaller when an app has a large viewstate.